# Texted selected on Firefox when using a jquery scrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, firefox, plugins, scrollbar

I tested many jQuery custom scrollbars and for all of them the text is selected when used with Firefox, like this:

[image]

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Sometimes it's even all the page that is selected.

Why? And how to avoid this Firefox behavior?

Comment: The issue you are describing is not verifiable. Please provide a [mcve]. From description, it looks like it's only happening in Firefox on your machine. It might be a plugin, an extension or malware.

Comment: Yes, it was because of the Firefox add on Enable right click and copy: https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/enable-rightclick-and-copy/?src=api